# MySQL Connector C#, MySQLDataRead.Read() only running when a value returned

Tags: c#, mysql-connector

As the name suggest's, this is an issue with the Reader's while loop only running when a value is returned. See below in this scenario, in the case of `if (email == rdr[0].ToString())` returns true, the while loop itself executes. However if it's not true the else does not execute. Also important to note that  `Debug.Log("Checking to see if the account exists");` only actually executes if the account exist's, as the check intends.

My assumption is, that if the Connector cannot find a row, it will not run the loop. How can I achieve this running?

Thanks.

```
 conn.Open();
            Debug.Log("SUCCESSFULL CONNECTION!");
            if (!isLogin)
            {
                Debug.Log("Is not login");
                bool doesEmailExist = false;
                string seecQuery = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = '"+ email +"'";
                Debug.Log(seecQuery);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(seecQuery, conn);
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Debug.Log("Checking to see if the account exists");
                    if (email == rdr[0].ToString())
                    {
                        Debug.Log("The account exists");
                        accountExists.SetActive(true);
                        //doesEmailExist = true;
                    }
                    else //if (!doesEmailExist)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Email is not in use. Starting OTA");
                        StartCoroutine(sendOTA()); // Start the OTP process
                        OTARead.SetActive(true);
                    }
```

Comment: If there is no rows at all (rather than a non-matching row) then yes, the loop will not execute. Not sure what else you would expect. Side points: you have **dangerous** SQL injection going on here, you need to use parameters. And `conn` `cmd` and `rdr` should be in `using` blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your primary issue is that the resultset has no rows, so `rdr.Read()` returns false on the first run and never executes the loop.

If the `email` column is unique, then all you want is a single result. For that you can obviate a reader and just use `cmd.ExecuteScalar`

- Note correct use of parameterization, preventing dangerous SQL injection
- Note `using` blocks, which will guarantee the connection gets closed in the event of an exception

```cs
bool doesEmailExist = false;
const string seecQuery = @"
SELECT 1
FROM accounts
WHERE email = @email;
";
Debug.Log(seecQuery);
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(yourConnString))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(seecQuery, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
    conn.Open();
    Debug.Log("SUCCESSFULL CONNECTION!");
    Debug.Log("Checking to see if the account exists");
    if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == (object)1)
    {
        Debug.Log("The account exists");
        accountExists.SetActive(true);
        //doesEmailExist = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Email is not in use. Starting OTA");
        StartCoroutine(sendOTA()); // Start the OTP process
        OTARead.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Just an update for this, I managed to fix the issue with a workaround.
Here it is. Rather than performing a while loop I checked to see if the Reader returned any rows or not. Worked fine.

```
conn.Open();
            Debug.Log("SUCCESSFULL CONNECTION!");
            if (!isLogin)
            {
                Debug.Log("Is not login");
                bool doesEmailExist = false;
                string seecQuery = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = '"+ email +"'";
                Debug.Log(seecQuery);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(seecQuery, conn);
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (!rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Email is not in use. Starting OTA");
                    StartCoroutine(sendOTA()); // Start the OTP process
                    OTARead.SetActive(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("The account exists");
                    accountExists.SetActive(true);
                }

                rdr.Close();
                conn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Please fix your SQL injection vulnerability. See the other answer, which is much better constructed than your workaround.